# Adding filler Objects to json in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I want to add the filler objects to the particular json key like here in feb-16 as it dont have jan-16 data i want to add jan-16 percentage as 0 and so on ..
I can use moment for date comparision in javascript..

json from server

```
{
'Jan-16': [
{
date: "Jan-16",
percentage: 100
},
{
date: "Feb-16",
percentage: 53
},
{
date: "Mar-16",
percentage: 45
},
{
date: "Apr-16",
percentage: 40
},
{
date: "May-16",
percentage: 39
},
{
date: "Jun-16",
percentage: 35
},
{
date: "Jul-16",
percentage: 34
},
{
date: "Aug-16",
percentage: 34
},
{
date: "Sep-16",
percentage: 26
}
],
 'Feb-16': [
{
date: "Feb-16",
percentage: 100
},
{
date: "Mar-16",
percentage: 53
},
{
date: "Apr-16",
percentage: 44
},
{
date: "May-16",
percentage: 40
},
{
date: "Jun-16",
percentage: 37
},
{
date: "Jul-16",
percentage: 35
},
{
date: "Aug-16",
percentage: 35
},
{
date: "Sep-16",
percentage: 27
}
],
 'Mar-16': [
{
date: "Mar-16",
percentage: 100
},
{
date: "Apr-16",
percentage: 51
 },
{
date: "May-16",
percentage: 43
},
{
date: "Jun-16",
percentage: 39
},
{
date: "Jul-16",
percentage: 37
},
{
date: "Aug-16",
percentage: 35
},
{
date: "Sep-16",
percentage: 28
}
]
```

and the json after filler i want is

```
{
'Jan-16': [
{
date: "Jan-16",
percentage: 100
},
{
date: "Feb-16",
percentage: 53
},
{
date: "Mar-16",
percentage: 45
},
{
date: "Apr-16",
percentage: 40
},
{
date: "May-16",
percentage: 39
},
{
date: "Jun-16",
percentage: 35
},
{
date: "Jul-16",
percentage: 34
},
{
date: "Aug-16",
percentage: 34
},
{
date: "Sep-16",
percentage: 26
}
],
 'Feb-16': [
{
date: "Jan-16",
percentage: 0
},
{
date: "Feb-16",
percentage: 100
},
{
date: "Mar-16",
percentage: 53
},
{
date: "Apr-16",
percentage: 44
},
{
date: "May-16",
percentage: 40
},
{
date: "Jun-16",
percentage: 37
},
{
date: "Jul-16",
percentage: 35
},
{
date: "Aug-16",
percentage: 35
},
{
date: "Sep-16",
percentage: 27
}
],
 'Mar-16': [
{
date: "Jan-16",
percentage: 0
}
{
date: "Feb-16",
percentage: 0
},
{
date: "Mar-16",
percentage: 100
},
{
date: "Apr-16",
percentage: 51
 },
{
date: "May-16",
percentage: 43
},
{
date: "Jun-16",
percentage: 39
},
{
date: "Jul-16",
percentage: 37
},
{
date: "Aug-16",
percentage: 35
},
{
date: "Sep-16",
percentage: 28
}
]
```

Comment: That's not JSON and even if you get the data as JSON, the problem doesn't have anything to do with JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to loop on your json and insert an object to it like..

```
for(j in json ) {

json[j][json.length] = {date:'Jan-16',percentage:0};

}
```

if you want to add from the first element you can use .unshift() like..

```
for(j in json ) {

json[j].unshift( {date:'Jan-16',percentage:0} );

}
```

From there you can do whatever comparing you want to do.